# How to handle click events of the settings button inside a UWP NavigationView?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I found that the official [NavigationView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview) are introduced in newer versions of Visual Studio and can help easily achieve the Hamburger layout, and by setting the property `IsSettingsVisible` to `True`, there will autometically be a settings button at the bottom.

My question is pretty simple: How can I handle the click event of this settings button? I cannot find any corresponding properties.

```xml
<NavigationView PaneDisplayMode="LeftCompact" IsSettingsVisible="True">
    <!--I'm expecting some codes like below-->
    <NavigationView.SettingsButton Click="SettingsButton_Click"/>
</NavigationView>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Register a new method to the `ItemInvoked` event and check if it's the Settings button which got invoked by doing so:

C#:

```
private async void NavigationView_ItemInvoked(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args) {
    if (args.IsSettingsInvoked) {
        // Code here
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<NavigationView IsSettingsVisible="True" ItemInvoked="NavigationView_ItemInvoked">
    <!-- Your XAML -->
</NavigationView>
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

The downside of the answer from Ramos is, that the setting button also gets selected, when clicked. If you want to open a contentdialog that is very likely not the right solution for you. I found a different approach:

```xml
<NavigationView.PaneFooter>
    <Button Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Height="40" Width="40"
            Click="SettingsButton_OnClick">
        <SymbolIcon Symbol="Setting"/>
    </Button>
</NavigationView.PaneFooter>
```

Also make sure to disable the other settings button with `IsSettingsVisible="False"`.

Note: The default icon size of the navigation view changed over time and became smaller. It is possible that 40 Pixel is not the correct size anymore in the future. You can correct that easily of course. [Link to the issue](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/1710)